# Magento 2.1: disable category filters

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, filter

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop.

The products are organized into *categories and subcategories*.

Whenever a customer visits a category, **filters** (links to its subcategories) are displayed. I want to disable the filters.

The path to the file responsible with the filters is

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/navigation/left.phtml

I want to overwrite it from `app/design/frontend/myCompany/myTheme/`.

1. How do I disable filters by coding?
2. Can the filters be disabled from Magento admin?

Comment: Do you want to remove all filters or just Subcategory type?

Comment: Can you tell me which filter options you want to remove? Or remove entire filteration part from category page?

Comment: I want to remove the links to the _subcategories_ from the _category pages_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme directory create ( if the file is not existing already ) 
`Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` and remove the block by adding the following line `<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />` do not forget to add the xml needed nodes. Your code should look something like the below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace code under **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}}/{themename}}/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml**

> From

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
        <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
    <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
            <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> To

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
        <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
    <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
    <?php  if($filter->getName() != __('Category')): ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
            <dd class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try configure:

`Store > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Categories > select category that you want > select tab Display Settings > select No > Save`

Comment: It will remove all products on the child category